# The devide of NaN plus number does not result the NaN value

Tags: java, double, nan

I'm using `Double.isNaN()` to detect NaN value. `

```
Double nan  = Double.NaN;
Double num  = 1.5;
Double num2 = 4.5;

Double result = (nan+num)/num2;

System.out.println(result);// the result is NaN

if(Double.isNaN(result))
   System.out.println("not NaN");//true
```

Is there any other way to detect NaN value?

Comment: `if(Double.isNaN(result))
        System.out.println("not NaN");` ?? is / not. Once fixed: https://ideone.com/KJrKxG it works as expected

Comment: Are you looking for `.isNaN()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Comment: *"Is there any **other** way to detect NaN value?"* Sure, `if (result != result)`, which is exactly what `Double.isNaN(result)` is doing.

Comment: IM sorry thats wrong question, wrong code. here is he problem but when im using the result for comparison the result variable is not an NaN but a small value.

Comment: Why are you using boxed `Double`? Use `double`!!

Comment: *"the result variable is not an NaN but a small value"* Nope. `result` is a `NaN` value.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition doesn't correspond to your output - you check if the result is in fact a NaN, but then print that it isn't. Either check that it isn't:

```
if (!Double.isNaN(result))
    System.out.println("not NaN"); // This won't be reached in your case
```

Or print that it is:

```
if (Double.isNaN(result))
    System.out.println("NaN");
```